# can not get memcached to run with laravel

Tags: php, laravel, memcached, laravel-4, mamp

I have read through al the questions here on memcached and after a frustrating time to get it compiled to the correct version of php and loaded into php laravel doesnt recognise my attempts.

running phpinfo yields this-

[image]

Yet laravel 4 yields this

[image]

I have tried restarting mamp- i dont know what else to do- its the same mamp install yield the two pics

Answer (score 1):

Although restarting mamp should have fixed this- rebooting my machine actually sorted this. not sure why!